# Dynamically generate URL from Database in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Hello to all developers,

I am trying to find some example of Dynamically generate URL(PURL).
I have seen one software which generate personalised URL from MySQL database .
The only thing is that software is using PHP to generate URL and as a .NET developer I dont know about php. 
My question is is there a way that I can fetch data from data base and using perticular field i can generate url which is not actually store in my web space..

```
eeg.
-----database-----

firstname  |  lastname .... 
=========================== 
xyz            abc
pqwert         qweoiuy 
alfa           beta
```

the URL should be like

`http://something.com/somepersonal/xyz_abc.aspx`

`http://something.com/somepersonal/pqwert_qweoiuy.aspx`

`http://something.com/somepersonal/alfa_beta.aspx`

It is something like personalised page for users or clients.
I have template to use as back page but dont know how to plug and dynamically generate URL..

Answer (score 1):

You're thinking of this a little backward.   Generally, one wouldn't do this by generating it directly from the database.  You would generally do this by routing the url batch `/somepersonal/` to some `personalpage` control, which would then consider everything after it, like `xyz_abc` to be an argument.  `Personalpage` would then use that argument to customize its display, be it from the database or wherever.

So to clarify, your URL would look something like:

```
http://something.com/personal/vish_soni
http://something.com/personal/colonel_gentleman
http://something.com/personal/general_specific
```

But all of these are being routed to `Personalpage`, which then uses `vish_soni`, `colonel_gentleman`, and `general_specific` as arguments to query the database or do whatever else it needs to do.

Microsoft has an overview of this pattern and routing in general [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/controllers-and-routing).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a controller class and call an action method. For your case, you just need to send parameter and then lookup customer info to prepare the content.

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Me(string id)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC! "+id;
        var contentobj = repository.GetUSerContent(id);
        return View("Index",contentobj);
    }
}
```